# How to fetch a Facebook user's public information through a Facebook ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to fetch a Facebook user's public information, but I am getting the error below.

I am trying this through [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)/[FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) after providing the Facebook id. For example, if I give a Facebook id as a number or robert.smith, through Graph API/FQL, I am able to fetch very limited information though the user has made other information publicly available.

If I manually go to that user's page, for example, here `robert.smith`, I am able to see a lot of information, like movies, sports, intests, etc. but through Graph API/FQL I am not able to fetch this information. Is there any other way to do it?

Also, one intersting point is, I tried to create a dummy profile with lots of public information and tried to fetch them through Graph API and then I got all the information. Is that something related to location in Facebook?

If users show public information on their wall, is there any way they can restrict not to provide information to APIs?

Comment: I've got the same question.  For instance, facebook.com/12345 shows a user and the hometown is visible in the left column.  I'm not a friend, but it's public.  When using the API 12345/?fields=hometown,name I only get the name.  hometown doesn't even come back null.  This is counterintuitive because the info is right there.  I would understand why FB would do this to prevent someone iterating every item in their catalog, but the docs are not clear on it.  Also..... scrapy!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what information you are looking for and what API queries your are trying to do to fetch it.
https://graph.facebook.com/me will indeed give you very limited information.

- To get all the likes you should use
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes
- To get all the movies, you should use
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/movies
  (change `me` to your target user id)

Full list of the Graph-API calls can be found here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

As for your other question about why you see things on the profile page and don't get it through the API, there could be a couple of reasons:

- Make sure your app has enough permissions (most common problem).  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
- There is much data you can not fetch through the API
- You are looking at a friend and see his data as a friend BUT he has not authorized your app, therefore some information is visible to you and not your app

It would help if you add the exact data your are looking for and the exact API calls you are making.

Comment: Respectful and please correct me if I am wrong, I think you are missing the point that Peter is asking for publicly shared information, and not information you get once you have an access token or have authenticated the user in your app.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/<insert_any_user_ID_here> will not work right? Is there any way to access on page info like location or study/work related info through graph api? because most of the time it reveals only very limited info about anyuser.